# how to enforce a div to size itself to include the collapsed elements

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor-server-side

*I am not sure someone has asked this, but I couldn't find the article.*

I am using Bootstrap 4.3.1.

I have a div that contains some collapsed elements.  When expand and collapse the elements, you can see the div adjusts itself size accordingly (ugly).  How can I restrict the div's size, so it doesn't change I toggle the collapse property of the elements?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
<div class="white-rounded-box flex-column mx-auto my-auto p-sm-5">
 <h2 class="d-flex align-self-center"
     style="color:var(--my-blue)">What would you like to do?</h2>

 <button class="btn btn-primary d-flex align-self-end mb-sm-1"
      type="button">
  Create a new request
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary d-flex align-self-end mt-sm-1"
      type="button">
Edit an old request
</button>
<MyBox class="collpase" />
</div>
```

**NOTE: The "white rounded box" is the div and MyBox is the collpased element.  The size of the "white rounded box" is the div in question.**

Comment: Can you give us some HTML and CSS with a screenshot of your desired output and screenshot or the problem you are facing. It helps us a lot.

Comment: @AhmadDalao...code snippet attached...it's got some C# code in it

Comment: A couple screenshots perhaps?

Comment: @PhillipS...unfortunately, I can't...the image website is blocked by the office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suspecting that Bootstrap must change the DISPLAY property to none (or similar) w/ it's Collapse class.  For my purpose, I still have the children to "take up space" when they are not visible.  So, I decided to take a different approach: using the VISIBILITY property instead of the Bootstrap class.